# How to mock a wrapper component with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jestjs

Assume the component is working, I have just removed useless code. In my component to test, I have this:

```
import {Container} from "flux/utils";
import Dialog from "material-ui/Dialog";
import React from "react";
...

class Component extends React.Component {
    state;

    static calculateState() {
        return {
            ...
        };
    }

    static getStores() {
        return [...];
    }

    ...

    render() {
        var actions = [...];

        return <Dialog
            actions={actions}
            open={this.state.open}
            title="foo"
            ...
        >
            <form ...>
                {/* My inputs and their values are according to the state. */}
            </form>
        </Dialog>;
    }
}

const MyComponent = Container.create(Component);

export default MyComponent;
```

In the UI, the inputs and their values are working. However, when I use Jest, it is not.

```
jest.mock('react-dom');
jest.mock('material-ui/Dialog', () => 'Dialog');

import Dispatcher from "../../dispatcher/Dispatcher";
import MyComponent from "../MyComponent";
import React from "react";
import Renderer from "react-test-renderer";

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    it('creates', () => {
        const component = Renderer.create(<MyComponent/>);
        let tree = component.toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            action: 'myComponent/open'
        });
        tree = component.toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

        tree.children[0].children[1].children[0].props.onChange(undefined, undefined, 'john');
        tree = component.toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

The first snapshot is good. The second snapshot is good too, the open property is changing. However, when I trigger the onChange of an input, the component state is updating, all good... but when I do the last snapshot, the children are still the same, event if the input values are different (and the state is well updated, confirmed).

I know this is due to the Dialog. If I remove it from the component class, the component works as expected... So how should I declare the mock?

Here is my last try:

```
jest.mock('material-ui/Dialog', () => {
    var React = require("react");

    return class extends React.Component {
        shouldComponentUpdate() {
            return true;
        }

        render() {
            var {children, ...rest} = this.props;

            return children;
        }
    }
});
```

The children are still the same :(

Comment: Just a guess but could it be a problem to get the callback from `component.toJSON()`? Have you tried to use enzyme like `component.find('Dialog').first().prop('onChange')(undefined, undefined, 'john')`, and then `expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();`